# How do I pass in a context from an activity to an ArrayAdapter in another class that's not an activity?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use an array of movies and put them in a listview. 
After debugging, the only thing that makes the activity crash is using getContext(). I tried getApplicationContext() and that also crashed the app. I'm not sure what to do. Here's a method in one class.

```
private void displayMovies(List<Movie> movies) {
     ArrayAdapter adapter = new
     ArrayAdapter(DisplayMoviesActivity.getContext(),
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, movies);
     ListView listView = DisplayMoviesActivity.getListView();
}
```

This is a different class.

```
public class DisplayMoviesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static ListView displayMoviesView;
static Context context;

public DisplayMoviesActivity(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_movies);
    displayMoviesView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.displayMoviesView);
    String searchText = (getIntent().getStringExtra("text"));
    RottenTomatoesJSON RTJSON = new RottenTomatoesJSON(this);
    RTJSON.searchMovieByName(searchText, 12);

}

public static Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public static ListView getListView() {
    return displayMoviesView;
}
}
```

The app crashes whenever I try to start the activity. 
This is the class I use to start the activity.

```
public void searchMovies(View v){
    SearchView searchBar = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    if (searchBar.isIconified() || searchBar.getQuery() == null || searchBar.getQuery() == "") {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Please enter movie to search!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    } else {
        String searchText = searchBar.getQuery().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMoviesActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("text",searchText);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I think this is the relevant logcat.

```
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2773(224KB)
  AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 931KB/1135KB, paused
 5.134ms total 40.550ms
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.956ms
 D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
 D/Atlas: Validating map...
 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface   0xa638a320, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: show the logcat, when the app crashes

Comment: welcome top
.
.
.i should know how your idée to work with références of fonctions, We know that class is description of object, soo, I sée références is very useful at setters méthods , ,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the constructor with `Context` parameter.

```
public DisplayMoviesActivity(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

instead,  pass the `Context` to your object of the `displayMovies` method.
Please provide the code of your class.

**NOTE**

You code makes clear that person who wrote it lacks common android development knowledge.

**END NOTE**

**Example:**

```
Helper helper = new Helper(this);
helper.displayMovies(//);
```

Comment: I can't reference it through a static context

Comment: @dirtysocks45 where are you using the method `displayMovies`?

Comment: It's in a class that's not an activity I believe. I'm working in a group, and someone else made it.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 You should pass the `context` in that class and use it there.

Answer (score 0):

A close look at [the docs for `Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) shows the following inheritance hierarchy:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
```

Note that `Context` is an ancestor of `Activity`. This means that an `Activity` **is a** `Context`. There is no need for a constructor in an `Activity` sublcass which accepts a `Context`. (Besides, this constructor will never be called.)

If the code which needs a `Context` occurs in a method inside your `Activity` subclass, you can just use `this` to refer to the current `Activity` object (which is also a `Context`):

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, movies);
```